# Login to AWS from AWS Tools for Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I'm trying to use AWS Tools from Powershell, but I don't know how to log in. So when I run a command I naturally get this error:

> No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.

How do I login? I read the article at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html, but it talks about public and private keys. I don't have those, I login to AWS from the web interface with my username and password (and also a token sent to my phone because I have MFA enabled).

Also, my user isn't allowed to create IAM users (it's a company policy and I can't override it).

Answer (score 18):

If your IAM user account doesn't already have Access and Secret Keys you'll need to create them here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey

Then create a profile

Writes a new (or updates existing) profile with name "myProfileName" in the encrypted SDK store file

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey akey -SecretKey skey -StoreAs myProfileName
```

Checks the encrypted SDK credential store for the profile and then
falls back to the shared credentials file in the default location

```
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName myProfileName
```

Comment: I don't have an IAM user account and I can't create one. My user account doesn't have permissions for that.

Comment: How do you log into the aws console then? If you want to use the cli you'll need credentials, you'll have to request them from whoever manages your AWS users.

Comment: It's described in my question - the next to last paragraph. I login from the browser, I'm asked about my username and password, and I get an authentication token on my phone. Then I'm logged into AWS management console - in the web browser. My account doesn't have permission to create IAM users.

Comment: I see that now. Back to my previous comment, you'll need to ask to get access and secret keys for your account, to use the cli.

Comment: Indeed it's not possible to do a classic username password authentication, even with TFA, for a program. The access and secret keys are actually more secure because they can be easily revoked. If your organization doesn't want to create for your profile then considering creating a set that works only for scripting. Those credentials can be circulated per day if security is of big concern.

Comment: You can set up STS, those credentials are only good for maximum of an hour.

Comment: @strongjz thank you, this was the solution I needed after a full hour of googling!